# onCompleted callback in useMutation doesn't have return values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to implement login in react native using apollo.
In react native app

```
const SIGN_IN = gql`
mutation($username: String!, $password: String!) {
  signin(password: $password, username: $username) {
    user {
      username
    }
    token
  }
}
`;
```

// code is abbreviated.

```
function LoginScreen() {
  const [signIn, { loading, error }] = useMutation(SIGN_IN, {
    onCompleted({ data }) {
      if (loading) console.log("Loading.....");
      console.log("Printing data");
      console.log(data.signin.token);
      }
  });
}
```

Backend server is working good.
But I got an error in console log says

```
    [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'signin' of undefined]

    Stack trace:
    screens/LogInScreen.js:36:6 in useMutation$argument_1.onCompleted
    node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:635:25 in callOncomplete
```

**data is undefined.**
So I tried `{ data && console.log(data.signin.token) }` But it prints nothing.
I read doc says "onCompleted callback to useMutation that will be called once the mutation is complete with its return value."

How can I debug this? what am I missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCompleted` is passed the entire data object as its first parameter, so your signature should look like this:

```
onCompleted(data)
```

or using destructuring

```
onCompleted({ signin })
```